# Ember application with an admin site

Tags: django, ember.js

I'm creating a basic Ember application. I am trying to set up a backend that stores posts. I would like to have a system where I can go to some admin site that has a form that has all the fields for a post that allows me to add, update, and delete posts. For example, if I have a `Post` model with attributes like Title, Contents, Date_created, and Image, I would like to have these fields in a form in some kind of admin site.

One example from a past tutorial I have done is the Django admin site. Is it possible to set up a Django backend for my Ember app? The Django admin is here: (scroll to bottom)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/

I know that asking how to set up a backend for my Ember application is a very general question, but I am confused as to where to start. I have already created a Post model with various attributes. I can create an Ember route that is a form to add a post, but then there comes authentication for that which I'm not really sure how to deal with either. That's why I came to Django because I remember they had a very nice admin site.

If it is not feasible to use Django to accomplish this, what are some other routes I can take to be able to get to some admin page where I can manipulate records and add new data to my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty big question, but I feel your pain. Most tutorials are all, "so... just build out a rails app... or use all this long lost stubbing stuff... or here's a super outdated node server on github to use."

I would suggest breaking it down into pieces. Ember is really great, but–Yes–you need a backend. You could make a backend with Django(python), Rails(ruby), WordPress(PHP) + ember-wordpress, express or hapi(node), phoenix(elixir)- or really anything that will generate an API. You could also build an admin with Ember and then use that to send data to a service like parse or firebase. Those could get you an MVP while you learn more about how to build out a traditional back-end.

Django + http://www.django-rest-framework.org has a pretty great admin setup that builds out the admin and fields from your API specifications. I can see why people like it.

I would also mention, that ember-cli-mirage is great when you aren't sure what backend you'll have, but you need to have a mock-server to build off of.

If you can, choose something that will spit out an API with jsonAPI.

I would split this into 2 parts.

1. build out an Ember app with Mirage or some other temporary data.
2. build a back-end somehow.

Then you can connect them ~ without being stuck beforehand.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I looked around and found  Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/). It was really easy to set up and they have specific instructions for Ember as well (EmberFire). I'm not sure how well this will suit my application but so far Google has done an amazing job of handling my data. 

However, my main question was exactly how Django would tie into my Ember app. I thought it would be difficult to get the two technologies working together, which is why I was wary to use Django. I didn't want to break my Ember app by adding something I had no idea how to integrate.

Comment: The Django app would have endpoints like `example.com:8000/api/posts` and then you would consume that JSON in your Ember front-end. They would be 2 different things. Ember would get data from the server, and possibly post back to that server.

Comment: The question seems to be mostly about 'admin' - and so, thinking about that some more... Django and Rails are the 2 that I know of - where you can actually just get an admin / fast. Maybe you should try Django + Django REST framework + https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api

Answer (score 1):

So pretty much a blog site where only person can create/delete/edit posts? If so then all you have to do is create a user with a predefined username and password in your Django app. You login through your Ember app. For this protected view you will need to use ember-simple-auth, which is the simplest way to implement something like this. Google ember-simple-auth and run its dummy app to see what they are doing.